# Need to backup, but can't press 'Trust Computer' button because of cracked screen

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, backup

I recently bought an iPhone 6s and wanted to bring my data from my old iPhone 4 to it but I have the following problem.

My iPhone 4 has a cracked screen and the sensor is a little messed up. If I try hard enough I can do almost anything (more than 10 times! and by rotating the screen if it can be rotated such as when I use the keyboard.)

I didn't have an iCloud account and used to backup with iTunes but after the screen was cracked I tried a couple of things and long story short I have no backups.

I tried creating an iCloud account and my contacts got transferred to my new iPhone but I can't find a way to transfer my notes as well.

The reason I can't backup the phone is because of a little screen that comes up when connected to iTunes that asks you to 'trust' the computer. Somehow it's the only thing/position in the screen the sensor isn't working. Same thing happens on iCloud, there is another screen asking you if you're sure you want to stop using iTunes and use iCloud and I can't get through it either.
I tried for hours.

I really want to transfer my notes on my new phone because it's 5 years worth of them and I want to keep them with dates etc etc...

Any suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: You will have to get your screen repaired.

Comment: Try turning on accessibility and control the phone with voice over.

Comment: I finally managed it with a two finger gesture!

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/237208/174658 for step-by-step instructions...

Comment: @System What's two finger gesture? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I finally solved the problem was to use the iPhone's AssistiveTouch. It can be enabled at the control center and when using the two finger gesture I was able to "click" on the "Trust This Computer" button that was otherwise unreachable since that part of the screen was unresponsive. I hope this helps others struggling with the same problem!