# Broken display on Iphone - cant 'Trust Computer'

Tags: iphone, screen, authentication

I recently dropped my iPhone from a height of 1 foot to the floor and now my screen is broken and unresponsive to input in some areas. In an attempt to salvage any data on the phone I wanted to connect it to my Macbook via USB cable. When I do so, there is a prompt on the computer to 'allow this device' to do something or other, and another prompt on the phone to 'Trust This Computer'. The issue is that the lower section of the screen that is damaged will not respond to input, so I am unable to finish the connection by pressing the prompt.

Is there way to turn off some setting that will automatically allow the device to connect to my Macbook? Or another way to salvage the data on the phone? I don't want to invest in a new screen as the phone is really old, and it would be a waste of money.

Comment: in [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/221863/need-to-backup-but-cant-press-trust-computer-button-because-of-cracked-scree) it is done using Assistive Touch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your iPhone display fails you still might be able to control it via Voice Control.

Trigger Siri and say "Enable Voice Control".
You can then trigger "screen taps" by saying "show grid" and saying the numbers shown on screen. You can find more information on [Apple Support - Use Voice Control](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210417)

Comment: Amazing workaround, but I cant even log into the phone now because the area on the passcode wont receive input.

Comment: You can use the grid on any part of iOS. After enabling Voice Control via Siri (which can be done even if the phone is locked), just say "show grid" and use it to input your passcode.

Comment: For some reason the phone wasn't connected to the internet any longer, so Siri was unavailable. I bit the bullet and bought a new screen.